# unable to find problems with this piece of code

Tags: java

I have this piece of code, I think I have all the braces covered. Still getting braces not closed error. When I put more braces, then gives me something else. Can you anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
    public static boolean isValid(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        if (year < 1900)
         {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            if (month>0 && month<13)
                {
                    if (month==1 || month==3 || month==5 || month==7 || month==8 || month==10 || month==12) 
                        {
                            return day > 0 && day <=31;

                        }
                    else if (month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11)
                        {
                            return day>0 && day<=30;
                         }
                    else if (month==2) 
                         {      
                            if (isLeap(year))
                                 {
                                    //(d= 29);
                                    return day>0 && day <=29;
                                 }

                                else {
                                    return day>0 && day<= 28;
                                 }
                         }
            }

        }
        }   
}
```

Comment: To start with, get rid of your `if([some boolean check]) { return true; } else { return false; }` blocks. Replace them with `return [some boolean check];`. That will reduce your number of braces and make your code clearer at the same time. (Use `return !([some boolean check])` if the `true` and `false` are reversed.) It might even resolve your error.

Comment: There does not seem to be a problem with braces. Probably some code preceding this method is causing a problem.

Comment: I've tryed that piece of code and works fine for me.
Have you tryed to use `else { if (...)` instead of `else if`?

Comment: @jpmc26, do you mean, something like this return(if(day > 0 && day <=31))?

Comment: This code has no problems. Check the code written before this.

Comment: @user1471980 for the outermost if else block, the else part is also missing a return value.

Comment: side note - consider using a `switch` block in place of your month checks.

Comment: @user1471980 Not quite. `day > 0 && day <=31` by itself evaluates to a boolean, so you can use it in the return statement directly: `return day > 0 && day <=31`. Placing the `if` where you did will generate a syntax error. You can use the parentheses on the very outside if they make you feel more comfortable, but they aren't required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your if-else conditions it may not be able to return a boolean value.That is the problem.Check your code's logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are missing any braces but you are not returning values for every possible execution path.

if you put a return false at the bottom of the function it will compile.

Little tip, to save the reader all of those nested ifs and braces:

```
if(day>0 && day<= 28){
  return true;
else{
  return false; 
}
```

you can do this:

```
return day > 0 && day <= 28;
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion as I updated my post, still getting the braces error.

Comment: Shortening the code is not the problem, the problem is *you are not returning values for every possible execution path.*.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using eclipse use ctrl shift f  to balance braces easier to read and see if you miss one or need one